# How to reindex List on the go?

Tags: java

My goal is to create a Dependency Injection Framework like Spring Framework. Right now I am trying to index a `List<Object> filteredServices` based on `Class<?>[] parameterTypes`

```
services -> filtered services based on parameterTypes of a constructor.
```

What I've done:

1. I use `Stream` to filter.

```
  public List<Object> getObjectsFromConstructorParameterTypes(Class<?>[] parameterTypes, List<Object> objects) {
    return objects
            .stream()
            .filter(object -> {
              for (Class<?> parameterType : parameterTypes) {
                if (parameterType.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
                  return true;
                }
              }
              return false;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

The sample parameterTypes and objects.

```
    List<Object> services = new ArrayList<>();
    services.add(IntegerServiceImpl.class.getConstructors()[0].newInstance());
    services.add(BooleanServiceImpl.class.getConstructors()[0].newInstance());

    getObjectsFromConstructorParameterTypes(HelloController.class.getConstructors()[0].getParameterTypes(),services);
```

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
  @Autowired
  private final IntegerService integerService;

  @Autowired
  private final BooleanService booleanService;

  public HelloController(IntegerService integerService, BooleanService booleanService) {
    this.integerService = integerService;
    this.booleanService = booleanService;
  }

  @GetMapping
  public String getHello() {
    return String.format("Hello %d %b", integerService.getRandomInt(), booleanService.getRandomBoolean());
  }
}
```

```
public class BooleanServiceImpl implements BooleanService {
  private final Random random = new Random();

  public boolean getRandomBoolean() {
    return random.nextBoolean();
  }
}
```

```
@Service
public class IntegerServiceImpl implements IntegerService {
  private final Random random = new Random();

  public int getRandomInt() {
    return random.nextInt();
  }
}
```

My expected result: There is method to reindex. e.g. `[serviceB, serviceA]` to `[serviceA, serviceB]`

My actual result: I could not find the method.

Related questions: Is `Stream` better than combination of nested `For Each` and initialization of `new ArrayList<>()`? I mean, is the underlying technology of `Stream` does not initialize new object when we call the method `collect()`, hence people prefer `Stream` or is there other reason?

```
  public List<Object> getObjectsFromConstructorParameterTypes(Class<?>[] parameterTypes, List<Object> objects) throws Exception {
    List<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Class<?> parameterType : parameterTypes) {
      for (Object object : objects) {
        if (parameterType.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())) {
          results.add(object);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (results.size() != parameterTypes.length) {
      for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
        if (!objects.get(i).getClass().isAssignableFrom(parameterTypes[i])) {
          throw new Exception(parameterTypes[i].getName() + " object has not been initialized.");
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
```

Comment: “_My goal is to create a Dependency Injection Framework like Spring Framework_” - might I suggest you just use Spring and find a somewhat simpler undertaking?

Comment: To answer your question - I do not know what you mean by “reindex”; what this method would do or what class it would be on. A `Stream` is a pipeline of operations that culminates in a terminal operation - like `collect()`. In your simple example there is no difference between using a `Stream` (declarative) or explicitly looping (imperative); the `collect` operation will indeed copy the result of the `Stream` to a new `List` (of an undefined type).

Comment: @BoristheSpider i am curious on how to build a framework, so i am trying to build one. `Reindex` i mean `List<Object> services` order is random e.g `[ServiceA,ServiceB]`, sometimes it can be `[ServiceB,ServiceA]`. So after `filter()`, I need to reindex it to always in the order I need, because I am going to use the `List<Object> filteredServices` to initialize the object.

Comment: Can you provide sample parameters to `getObjectsFromConstructorParameterTypes`, your expected return value and the return value you actually get?

Comment: @tgdavies please wait, i will update it, please kindly check in a minute.